# Is it possible to change the “From:” address of a distribution list to to the distribution list e-mail address and not the sender’s email address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I created a distribution group in the cloud and set “Send As” permissions for some users. Could I change the “From:” field to the distribution list e-mail address of Outlook 2019’s new messages for these users permanently?

I get my Office 365 users from my on-premises AD by syncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you wouldn't like to change the From filed manually every time and hope the default address in From field is the distribution group's address?

If so, as I know, the default address in From field depends on the default account in your Outlook, it means we could change it via add other account and change it as the default account, but it seems to not apply to a distribution list.

So I think you may need other tools or macros to meet your requirement, based on my research, maybe this [article](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/setfromaddress.htm) could help you, please kindly check it.